# Are mysql inserts are always consecutive?

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
insert into tbl(name)values('john'),('bale'),('ron')
```

if a person runs this query and another person at different part of the world runs

```
insert into tbl(name)values('johnny'),('baleton'),('ronny')
```

this at **few seconds after previous query but before its completion** on a server. Wil the values inserted be consecutive? Like  this

```
'john','bale','ron','johnny','baleton','ronny'
```

or it may not be the `tbl` has `id|name` as columns.

Comment: "consecutive" has no real meaning in relational databases. there's sets of data. YOU add  'order' to those sets by adding things like auto-increment primary keys. The db itself couldn't care less what order things are in.

Comment: Sidenote: Just you be careful when letting a whole bunch of people you (probably) don't know, inserting whatever without taking guard against SQL injection.

Comment: Look into isolation levels, they can control how this type of situation is handled.

Comment: @Markb i have `id` as primary key AI

Comment: Why do you want things to be "consecutive" or "in order"?  It sounds like you're relying on a side effect that you shouldn't be.

Comment: @user3508453: "Isolation level" is a property of transactions, that says how strictly you want the transaction to enforce the guarantees transactions can provide.  It can range from "serializable" (the strictest, most reliable, most locky, and thus usually most expensive) to "read uncommitted" (which is almost worse than no transaction at all -- basically all you get is the ability to roll back, and conceivably even that might get wonky).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe each query in MySQL happens in single transaction (if autocommit is enabled). If you manage your transaction yourself that then the situation is even more obvious. 
I believe that for this reason the records will be inserted in order.

**Edit:**

I assume this is all about `autoincrement` otherwise the question doesn't make sense as explained in comment under the original question.

I stand corrected. The [doc states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html):

`When accessing the auto-increment counter, InnoDB uses a special table-level AUTO-INC lock that it keeps to the end of the current SQL statement, not to the end of the transaction.`

So yes, still in order. Not for scope of transaction but single SQL statement.

Comment: The insert happens in scope of single transaction (regardless autocommit) so I believe the ordering will be kept.

`Will the values inserted be consecutive?` => **YES**

Comment: What if a single query with 100 rows to be inserted takes 10 min to complete.
And the 2nd query is ran before 1st's completion

Comment: @user3508453 Please don't ask questions in comments.  You may edit and add to your initial question to make it clearer, or ask a new question.

Comment: I also stand corrected, I appear to have read my own source incorrectly.  +1

Answer (score 0):

MySQL (at least with the InnoDB engine) will assign the next Auto Increment value (ai_max + ai_increment) to the first statement (not transaction) that reads the table on INSERT.  So if another statement comes along, attempts to INSERT, and finalizes before the first, it gets the NEXT AI value (ai_max + 2*ai_increment), not the one assigned to the first statement.

This is about as "in order" as databases get.

For more information on MySQL InnoDB Auto Increment, see [the MySQL developer's reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html)